# Delete from two tables (look if data exists)

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble to delete data from my two tables in one query. 
I've found several similar threads but none that has the same core problem as me.

So, why is this different?

*The target:* I need help on how to delete all the project data from my `project` database, and also all the hours that is **eventually** attached to it in the `hours` database.

With my current query it only deletes if it finds a match in both the `project` and the `hours` databases. So how could I achieve it to delete all the data as requested above?

Right now my query looks like this:

```
DELETE hours, projects
FROM hours 
INNER JOIN projects  
WHERE hours.projecthours_id= projects.project_id and hours.projecthours_id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']).";
```

This is my two tables (example data and tables):

```
#hours
---------------------------------------
hours_id  projecthours_id  amount_hours 
1         12               15
2         8                4
3         9                2
4         15               11

#projects
---------------------------------------
project_id  project_name  
1           project 1
2           project 2
3           project 3
4           project 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get it to work thorugh one query. 
So made them as two separate ones instead.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM hours WHERE hours.projecthours_id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."";

$mysqli->query($query);
$query = "DELETE FROM projects WHERE projects.project_id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try left outer join instead of inner join and `where` goes to `on`.

Try this

```
DELETE hours, projects
FROM hours 
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects on hours.projecthours_id= projects.project_id
WHERE hours.projecthours_id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']).";
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use `Left Join` instead of `Inner Join`.
- Also, your `where` condition should be on `projects.project_id` instead of `hours.projecthours_id`, as you are trying to delete all from `projects` table.

Try:

```
DELETE hours, projects
FROM hours 
LEFT JOIN projects ON projects.project_id = hours.projecthours_id
WHERE projects.project_id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']).";
```